# Python / PyQt4: How to make a QComboBox Item draggable

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt4

I'm just tinkering with PyQt for fun...

I have the following code so far which accepts drops from a text field to populate the QComboBox:

```
class ComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):
def __init__(self, parent):
    super(ComboBox, self).__init__(parent)

    self.setAcceptDrops(True)

def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
    if e.mimeData().hasFormat('text/plain'):
        e.accept()
    else:
        e.ignore()

def dropEvent(self, e):

    self.addItem(QtCore.QString(e.mimeData().text()))
```

I would now like to make the items in the QComboBox draggable (like you can do with a QLineEdit using the following method:

```
.setDragEnabled(True)
```

Anyone know how I could go about this?

Many Thanks

P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `combobox.view().setDragDropMode(Qt.QAbstractItemView.DragOnly)` to enable dragging. The following working example illustrates how to implement dragging items from one combobox to another:

```
combobox = Qt.QComboBox()
combobox.addItems(["test1", "test2", "test3"])
combobox.show()
combobox.view().setDragDropMode(Qt.QAbstractItemView.DragOnly)

model_mime_type = 'application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'

class ComboBox(Qt.QComboBox):
  def __init__(self):
    super(ComboBox, self).__init__()
    self.setAcceptDrops(True)

  def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
    if e.mimeData().hasFormat(model_mime_type) or \
       e.mimeData().hasFormat('text/plain'):
      e.accept()
    else:
      e.ignore()

  def dropEvent(self, e):
    if e.mimeData().hasFormat(model_mime_type):
      encoded = e.mimeData().data(model_mime_type)
      stream = Qt.QDataStream(encoded, Qt.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
      while not stream.atEnd():
        row = stream.readInt()
        column = stream.readInt()
        map = stream.readQVariantMap()
        if len(map.values()) == 1:
          self.addItem(map.values()[0].toString())     
      combobox.hidePopup()   
    else:
      self.addItem(Qt.QString(e.mimeData().text()))

c2 = ComboBox()
c2.show()
```

Comment: thank you, that's perfect! if i had enough points I would up-vote!